# How to change the value of the String variable of Videoview URL after click Button?

Tags: android, string, button, android-activity, android-videoview

i want play many videos in same videoview 
when click on button , The online video play in videoview in other layout
example :

there are three button in "layout 1"
after click on any button go to "layout 2"
there is one VideoView in "Layout 2 "
everyone action Click on Button is Change String Value "VideoURl" in VideoView

The question is : How can I change the value of the String variable in the Layout 2 When you click on any button in the Layout 1?!!][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytQiE.jpg)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytQiE.jpg

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
Button button1;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}
     public void addListenerOnButton() {
          final Context context = this;

            button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);


            button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                    Intent i = new Intent(context, Main2Activity.class);
                    i.putExtra("VidURL1", "http://img580.imageshack.us/img580/416/4dojlrwiknaexgxaiyqfbz.mp4");

                                startActivity(i);   

                }

            });


    }

  }
```

The Code activity 2 :

```
public class Main2Activity extends Activity {

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

VideoView videoview;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

   new StreamVideo().execute();


   }


   private class StreamVideo extends AsyncTask {

   @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {

       super.onPreExecute();
       pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Main2Activity.this);
       pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
       pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
       pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
       pDialog.show();

   }

   @Override
   protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return null;
   }

   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

       try {
           // Start the MediaController
           MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                   Main2Activity.this);
           mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
           // Get the URL from String VideoURL
           Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
           videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
           videoview.setVideoURI(video);

           videoview.requestFocus();
           videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
               // Close the progress bar and play the video
               public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                   pDialog.dismiss();
                   videoview.start();
               }
           });
       } catch (Exception e) {
           pDialog.dismiss();
           Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

   }

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: Why are you using an `AsyncTask` which does nothing in its `doInBackground(...)` method? In answer to your question, change the URL passed from `Activity` 1 in the `Intent` extra depending on which button is pressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  pass data between two activity using intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SignoutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID", sessionId);

startActivity(intent)
```

and to get data from the activity1

```
String Url = getIntent().getExtras().getString("yourKey");
```